# ELCImagePickerController shows just black screen + navigation bar with Swift

Tags: swift, elcimagepickercontroller

I am trying to implement the ELCImagePickerController, but when I try to present the picker, just a black screen shows up with a navigation bar at the top. I moved all files(also the xib) into my project :/ Is this a problem because of swift/ios8 ?

```
 var imagePicker:ELCImagePickerController = ELCImagePickerController();
    self.presentModalViewController(imagePicker, animated: true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are just calling the `init` method instead of the proper `initImagePicker` that is *expected to be used* (See the [source here](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController/blob/master/Classes/ELCImagePicker/ELCImagePickerController.h#L44)).

If you instantiate in like this it works:

```
var picker = ELCImagePickerController(imagePicker: ())
```

Note that the name is weird because of the automatic conversion that Xcode does for you of the Objective-C method by removing the `init` part of the name.

Also note that you don't need to specify that `picker` is of type `ELCImagePickerController` because Swift *infers* it automatically.

Hope this helps :)